# Remove UISegmentedControl separators completely. (iphone)

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

Is there a way to completely remove the line separating the two segments in a UISegmentedControl?

Setting the `segmentedControlStyle` is not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. You should look into creating the UISegmentedControl functionality manually. Maybe use two UIButtons.

Comment: starting from iOS 5.0 There is a way, using a thin UIImage like Naveed suggested below.

Answer (score 34):

If anybody wants this kind of `UISegmentedControl View`-

[image]

**EDITED:-** **Swift 3.0** extensions

```
    extension UISegmentedControl {

    func customizeAppearance(for height: Int) {

        setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size:13.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white], for:.normal)
        setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size:13.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white], for:.selected)
        setDividerImage(UIImage().colored(with: .clear, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: height)), forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        setBackgroundImage(UIImage().colored(with: .clear, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: height)), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        setBackgroundImage(UIImage().colored(with: UIColor.init(red: 215/255.0, green: 0.0, blue: 30/255.0, alpha: 1.0), size: CGSize(width: 1, height: height)), for: .selected, barMetrics: .default);

        for  borderview in subviews {
            let upperBorder: CALayer = CALayer()
            upperBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 215/255.0, green: 0.0, blue: 30/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            upperBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: borderview.frame.size.height-1, width: borderview.frame.size.width, height: 1)
            borderview.layer.addSublayer(upperBorder)
        }

    }
}

extension UIImage {

    func colored(with color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor);
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: size)
        context!.fill(rect);
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image!
    }
}
```

The `UIImage` extension generates a colored image with desired size.

Forcing the `height` parameter in `customizeAppearance` avoid any crash when building the `context`.

You can make it even more reusable by extracting each customization attribute and put it as function's parameters ;)

Here is sample code, tested over iOS 9 and works fine for me.

Add these lines of code in `viewDidLoad`-

```
[yourSegmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-black" size:13.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor] }forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[yourSegmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-black" size:13.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor] }forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[yourSegmentControl setDividerImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor]] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[yourSegmentControl setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor]] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[yourSegmentControl setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:215/255.0 green:0 blue:30/255.0 alpha:1.0]] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

for (UIView *borderview in yourSegmentControl.subviews) {

    CALayer *upperBorder = [CALayer layer];

    upperBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:215/255.0 green:0 blue:30/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

    upperBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, borderview.frame.size.height-1, borderview.frame.size.width, 1.0f);

    [borderview.layer addSublayer:upperBorder];
}
```

and

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Here is the **Swift** extension for achieving same view in Swift-

```
yourSegmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size:13.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:UIControlState.Normal)

yourSegmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size:13.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:UIControlState.Selected)

yourSegmentControl.setDividerImage(self.imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forLeftSegmentState: UIControlState.Normal, rightSegmentState: UIControlState.Normal, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)

yourSegmentControl.setBackgroundImage(self.imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forState:UIControlState.Normal, barMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default)

yourSegmentControl.setBackgroundImage(self.imageWithColor(UIColor.init(red: 215/255.0, green: 0.0, blue: 30/255.0, alpha:1.0)), forState:UIControlState.Selected, barMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default);

for  borderview in yourSegmentControl.subviews {

let upperBorder: CALayer = CALayer()
upperBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 215/255.0, green: 0.0, blue: 30/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
upperBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, borderview.frame.size.height-1, borderview.frame.size.width, 1.0);
borderview.layer .addSublayer(upperBorder);

}
```

and

```
func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {

    let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, yourSegmentControl.frame.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image

}
```

Comment: Seems to remove the corner radius of the control. Any idea how I can add it back?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 23):

Use this method to change your segment divider image:

```
[segmentControl setDividerImage:dividerimg
            forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
              rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                     barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 21):

I combined the previous answers into a **Swift** extension.

I wanted to remove all borders and dividers. This code just uses the normal segment colors, e.g. tint and background for selected / deselected.

Call

```
segmentedControl.removeBorders()
```

Here's the extension

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func removeBorders() {
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(backgroundColor!), forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(tintColor!), forState: .Selected, barMetrics: .Default)
        setDividerImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor()), forLeftSegmentState: .Normal, rightSegmentState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
    }

    // create a 1x1 image with this color
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use explicit colors in lieu of `backgroundColor!` and `tintColor!`, otherwise you may find nil while unwrapping. Otherwise, brilliant!

Comment: @dperk Good point if the code is generic it should handle background and tint set to nil. These could either be an argument to removeBorders() or I make defaults when they're not set. Not sure how the control finds defaults for these when not set but could find out & do the same. For now make sure tintColor and backgroundColor are set ;)

Comment: Question: everytime I tap a segment, I get a light gray rectangle in the background of that segment. It only appears as I'm tapping and disappears after the tap. It looks pretty ugly. How would I remove this?

Comment: By calling setBackgroundImage with: imageWithColor(UIColor.clearColor() ) for the .Highlighted state.

Comment: I am currently doing this, and I am having an issue. If I EVER call setBackgroundImage for the Normal state, and I try to PROGRAMMATICALLY change the selected index of the UISegmentedControl, the icons' tint does NOT update.  Only the highlighting color updates. Therefore you have this dim icon that you can barely see.  Has anybody else seen or fixed this?

Answer (score 14):

The following code will do exactly what you want.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1, self.segControlOut.frame.size.height), NO, 0.0);
UIImage *blank = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.segControlOut setDividerImage:blank
                forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                  rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                         barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Prefer to `[UIImage new]` for blank image.

Answer (score 10):

You can remove all background, border and separators from a UISegmentedControl by setting a black image. Or you can set custom colours.

The below example removes all borders/seperators, and sets the background to be white with 0.2 alpha, and the selected segment to be white with alpha 1.0

```
[self.segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.2]] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0]] forState:UIControlStateSelected  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: I am currently doing this, and I am having an issue. If I EVER call setBackgroundImage for the Normal state, and I try to PROGRAMMATICALLY change the selected index of the UISegmentedControl, the icons' tint does NOT update. Only the highlighting color updates. Therefore you have this dim icon that you can barely see. Has anybody else seen or fixed this?

Answer (score 6):

I have used `segmentcontrol.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];` with iOS7 and it seems to work.

Comment: No, this makes the entire UISegmentedControl invisible!!

Comment: making tint color clear makes title color clear as well.. I do not think this a good solution.

Comment: It's a great solution if you also call `setTitleTextAttributes` and pass font attributes with a color for each of the normal, highlighted, and selected states.

Comment: Yea its what i need! ty @par and palaniraja

Answer (score 5):

@naveed's and  @Jon Setting's answers saved my day!

But as a bit of a perfectionist, i was frustrated to find out that this code also leaves holes in the outer border of the control:

[image: Before]

So I added a few lines of code to get rid of those and make it look neat:
[image: After]

The complete code for this would be

```
CGFloat h = self.segControlOut.frame.size.height;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1, h), NO, 0.0);

// draw the missing dots with the control border color
[self.segControlOut.tintColor set];
UIRectFrame( CGRectMake(0, -1, 1, 2.5) );
UIRectFrame( CGRectMake(0, h-1.5, 1, 2.5) );

UIImage *blank = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.segControlOut setDividerImage:blank
                forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                  rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                         barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) configSegmentControl {
    [segmentControl setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [segmentControl setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]] forState:UIControlStateSelected  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    segmentControl.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
    segmentControl.clipsToBounds = YES;
}

- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```