# UISegmentControl bottom line on selected index

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

My `UISegmentControl` has no borders and segment separators. I want to place a line below the selected segment. I tried doing this :

```
CALayer *bottomLayer = [CALayer layer];
bottomLayer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
bottomLayer.borderWidth = 3;

// Calculating frame
CGFloat width            = segment.frame.size.width/segment.numberOfSegments;
CGFloat x                = 0;
CGFloat y                = segment.frame.size.height - 5;
bottomLayer.frame       = CGRectMake(x, y,width, 2);

[bottomLayer setName:@"bottom"];
// Adding selection to segment
[segment.layer addSublayer:bottomLayer];
```

This puts a line when I tap the segment. But when I release the tap, line is no more seen. I am using `UIControlEventValueChanged` as the controlEvent.
How may I achieve this **without** using third party.

Comment: You cannot achieve without third party, but i suggest you use button and imageview for line. animate the imageview under the button using uiview animation. this is the best and simple way.

Answer (score 0):

UISegmentedControl is a class that inherits from UIView so you can add/remove subviews to it. So instead of CALayer I would recommend using a UIView or UIImageView to place the line underneath.

```
UIView *bottomView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bottomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

// Calculating frame
CGFloat width            = segment.frame.size.width/segment.numberOfSegments;
CGFloat x                = 0;
CGFloat y                = segment.frame.size.height - 5;
bottomView.frame         = CGRectMake(x, y,width, 2);

// Adding selection to segment
[segment addSubview:bottomView];
```

Instantiate your subviews globally so you can remove them or change it's opacity (i.e. `bottomView.alpha = 0`) at `UIControlEventValueChanged`,

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by getting selected `subview` of `segment control`. Here is sample code put this into `viewDidLoad` for default selected segment and put in `UIControlEventValueChanged`-

```
CALayer *bootomBorder = [CALayer layer];
bootomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
bootomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, userProfileSagmentOutlet.subviews[userProfileSagmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex].frame.size.height-1, userProfileSagmentOutlet.frame.size.width/userProfileSagmentOutlet.numberOfSegments-2, 1.0f);
[userProfileSagmentOutlet.subviews[userProfileSagmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex].layer addSublayer:bootomBorder];
```

You can also refer this link may this will help you- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37705692/5097148