# Where to call segmentedControl.removeBorders() from?

Tags: swift, call, uisegmentedcontrol

When I'm creating an extension in Xcode and need to call:

> segmentedControl.removeBorders()

Where should I call that from?. In `viewDidLoad` for the view controller's Swift file? as an override func in the view controller's Swift file?. Inserting that after viewDidLoad is giving me a "Method 'segmentedControl' was used as a property; add () to call it" error and when I add the parentheses it gives me a

> "Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'removeBorders'" error.

Is it an issue with naming? I named the .swift for deleting the borders/dividers "UISegmentedControl+removeborders.swift". I'm a complete n00b, if that helps to explain why I'm stuck on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**Reference**: The 3rd answer listed for this question regarding removing the border/dividers from UISegmentedControl: [Remove UISegmentedControl separators completely. (iphone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314927/remove-uisegmentedcontrol-separators-completely-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

In my current project, I've subclassed it, so the call is made in the initializer:

```
class SegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    override init(items: [Any]?) {
        super.init(items: items)
        segmentedControlInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        segmentedControlInit()
    }
    private func segmentedControlInit() {
        removeBorders()
    }
}
```

But doing it from viewDidLoad should be fine as well.